# Matlab 'bridge' 'shrink' and 'holes' equivalent morphological operations in openCV

Tags: matlab, opencv, python

I am trying to bridge unconnected pixels in an image using opencv-python. In matlab there is bmmorph function which takes in 'bridge' operation which does this. I am trying to do similar thing using opencv-python. Can anyone tell me what is the equivalent of bridge operation in opencv?

Similarly I am looking for 'shrink' and 'holes' operation too.

[Here](https://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html) is the reference I am using:

Comment: Have you tried anything or are you looking for a tutorial/suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about opencv, but there is a hole filling function in `scipy.ndimage.morphology` called `binary_fill_holes`.

I usually import it as `imfill` because I am used to using morphology in Matlab:

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_fill_holes as imfill
```

Then depending on your needs, you can use it with no parameters (that way it's closest to `imfill(BW,conn,'holes')` in Matlab), or use it with different parameters, as given in the documentation of the function: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_fill_holes.html

Haven't found bridge function yet though, looking for one myself.

I hope I helped, all the best!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I ended up writing my own bridge function. It's bit rusty but does the trick.

Comment: @always_learning_alien That's great! :)

If you think that the answer helped you and answered your question, you can mark it as an accepted answer.

All the best!